# How does a boolean variable work in an object array

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an object array for movies that can be rented and the boolean variable will show if the movies is available or not. How do I code it in the getter/setter?

```
public class Film
{
    private String movieid;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private double price;
    private boolean status;
}
```

Comment: `void setStatus(boolean newStatus) { status = newStatus; }` ?

Comment: What does an array of movies have to do with how to write a getter/setter on the status of a Film?

Comment: I don't understand the question. simple POJO Getters/Setters are the easiest thing to code there is. In fact so easy that you can simply have them generated for you by your IDE like Eclipse. What do you think would be different about a boolean getter/setter than any other getter and/or setter?

Comment: Yeah I understand It's a strange questions. I just never used booleans as a variable inside an object array before.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're trying to ask.  You still don't have a boolean variable inside an object array, you have a boolean variable inside your `Film` class.  Are you talking about a `Boolean[]` or something?

Comment: Sorry, I plan to make a Film[ ]

Comment: How instances of `Film` may be stored is irrelevant to the methods on it.  Just have your IDE generate the getters and setters as normal, like @OHGODSPIDERS said.

Comment: @RobinBorg Why do you think it matters to the get/set methods of `Film` whether the `Film` object is used directly, or as part of an array?

Comment: *Unrelated:* What does "status" mean, as a boolean? If status is true, what does that mean? What does false mean? If that boolean is supposed to *"show if the movies is available or not"*, then name it `available` so it correctly identifies the meaning of true/false value. That also fits with normal bean getter method naming for boolean values, which is to name the getter `isAvailable()`, and the setter `setAvailable(boolean available)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to create an array of `Film` objects (as in `Film[]`) then you would call the getter and setter methods of a specific `Film` within the array like:

```
filmList[i].getStatus();
```

where `filmList` is your `Film` array and `i` is the index of the specific `Film` in the array.